# Magento Products Sort by Category

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I need to sort the product list in `productCollection` by `Category`.

I need this facility because in my site i have to display *New Products* and *Special Products* in separate page(tab).

I could even use `addAttributetoSort()` for `sku`, `news_to_date`, `news_from_date`, `name`, `price` etc. But could not use `category_id`. It has no effect.

I know I can set it from admin panel in **Manage Attribute**. In **Manage Attribute** `price`, `name` is available to sort. Even I can create `sku`, `news_to_date` etc as attribute in from **Manage Attribute**. But when I create attribute code as `category` or `category_id`, it comes with an error like

```
System reserved category/category_id
```

Means I could not use `category` or `category_id` as attribute from **Manage Attribute** (As they are reserved by the System).

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this will sort by category:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('category_ids', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku', 'status', 'visibility', 'is_saleable'))
;
```

Comment: You should edit your anwser since there's no attribute named `category_idS`. The right name is `category_id`

Comment: ->addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'ASC') does not work for me

Answer (score -1):

That works for me:

```
    $category ='1503'; // Is in my case Categoryid of New Products Category

    $_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $_products->load();
```

Regards